# vim add text to beginning of multiple lines excluding white space with substitution

Tags: vim

I have the following paragraph:

```
1 sometexthere  
2     indented text
3     indented text
4     indented text
```

I would like to use vim's search and replace command to add some text right before indented text. For example:

```
1 sometexthere  
2     test: indented text
3     test: indented text
4     test: indented text
```

Is there a way to use vim's search and replace syntax to achieve the following results? I have tried commands like
`2,4s/^/test: /` but still can't figure out a way to strip off the whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching leading whitespace and replacing it by itself:

```
%s/^\s\+/&test: /
```

Or matching lines by `:global` and editing them by `:normal`

```
g/^\s/normal! Itest:
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am misunderstanding you question you can achieve this fairly simply like:

```
%s/    /\    test:/g
```

This gives the output you desire from the given input.
For this though, i prefer to use a macro.

```
qq         # Begin recording the macro
/____      # Search for four spaces
4li        # Insert four characters to the right
test:      # Type the desired text
<ESC>q     # Exit insert mode and save the macro to the q register
```

Then to run this macro on the next indent go `@q`. Just repeat `@q` or `@@` to keep running the macro until everything is indented.

Another alternative route, which is fairly readable, is to use the normal command.

```
/____                      # Search for the indent.
:'<,'> normal 0nitest:     # Inserts "test:" 4 characters right of the search result. you can replace the <,> with a range of course.
```